# Where on product pages should customer reviews be placed?

Tags: seo, page, user-reviews

Is it better to have reviews at the bottom of a page like Amazon does, or does the location of reviews not matter too much? Are there any case studies to show the best placement for people to view reviews? Should there be a separate page to view all reviews for a product, which could be optimised for SEO?

Comment: I would put the reviews wherever it makes the most sense so that the user has a good experience.

Answer (score 3):

Set a review on the page the content of which is described by the subject of the review. Choose the place for the revocation yourself. A good solution for UX is to indicate the most important info at the top of the document (before the fold).
Google, in its guide to structured data for review, **[says](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#technical-guidelines)**:

> Make sure the reviews and ratings you mark up are readily available to
> users from the marked-up page. It must be immediately obvious to users
> that the page has review content.